# React Native redux. Sending a reference of the element,onPress, to an action creator

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

```
 <TouchableWithoutFeedback  onPress={()=>this.props.selectCell()}>                      

    <Row  style={[styles.orangish,styles.cell]}>                        
        <Image source={Rain} />
    </Row>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

I have a 8 tile elements bound by TouchableOpacity. I want the function to know which tile is being pressed. How do I send something like an `id` to the action creator, or any other function for that matter

Answer (score 0):

It might be a little bit late to answer this, but anyway, you can access the referenced element by passing the event and then accessing its target element, like this:

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback  onPress={(e) => this.props.selectCell(e.target)}>
    <Row  style={[styles.orangish,styles.cell]}>                        
        <Image source={Rain} />
    </Row>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Then, on your action creator you could access to the element as you would normally do:

```
export function selectCell(element){
    ...
}
```

I hope this helps...